# Update scriptlets in HTML without reloading page

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, template-engine

I am referring to this article about templated HTML and scriptlets with Google Apps Script:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates

It is written how to call an Apps Script function and load the data when loading the html page:

Code.gs:

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('Index')
      .evaluate();
}

function getData() {
  return SpreadsheetApp
      .openById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
      .getActiveSheet()
      .getDataRange()
      .getValues();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <? var data = getData(); ?>
    <table>
      <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
        <tr>
          <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
            <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
          <? } ?>
        </tr>
      <? } ?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Question:
Is it possible to update the scriptlets without refreshing the whole page?
For example to implement a button and call the `getData()` function to load new data from the spreadsheet to the html?

**Update:**

I have adjusted the code with a simple button and a code to call the `getData()` function again and update the table. But of course doing it this way the for loop gets lost. Better would be to reload the whole code.
Is there a way to re-evaluate the whole page?
Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" onclick="Refresh()">Refresh</button>
    <? var data = getData(); ?>
    <table id="datatable">
      <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
        <tr>
          <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
            <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
          <? } ?>
        </tr>
      <? } ?>
    </table>
  </body>

<script>

  function Refresh(){
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(update).withUserObject(this).getData();
  }      
            
  function update(returnValue){
    document.getElementById("datatable").innerHTML= returnValue
  }

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: `google.script.run`

Comment: Documentation Say:`Remember, however, that because template code executes before the page is served to the user, these techniques can only feed initial content to a page. To access Apps Script data from a page interactively, use the google.script.run API instead.`

Comment: Yes, I have read that and know how to call the getData() function. But I dont know how to update the scriptlet or to re-evaluate the html. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you want that the DOM be updated? Do you want to use a button for that? How do you will include the required JavaScript for the client-side? Please edit the question to add more details including a brief description of your search efforts for helpful answers from this site as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: I have made an upate of my question with the button and the current issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will call `getData()` from the client-side, then you will need to build the table on the client-side. The easier way might be to create a string and then add it by using `HtmlElement.outerHTML` to replace the whole element or `HtmlElement.innerHTML` to replace the inner elements and content.

Client-side JavaScript code (put it between `<script>` tags, do not require to change your server-side code)

```
function refreshTable(){
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(updateTable)
    .withFailureHandler((error) => console.error(error.message))
    .getData()

}

function updateTable(data){
  let html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    html += `<tr>`;
      for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
        html += `<td>${data[i][j]}</td>`;
      } 
    html += `</tr>`;
  }
  document.getElementById("datatable").innerHTML = html;
}
```

By the other hand, if you want to use Google Apps Script templated HTML to build the HTML table, then you need to call a function that evaluates the template to generate a HttpOutput object and then use `HttpOutput.getContent()` to return a string to the client side code, then you might pass this string to the corresponding element by using `HtmlElement.innerHTML`.

Server Side, in a .gs file

```
function includeFromTemplate(filename){
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(filename).evaluate().getContent();
}
Server side, table.html file
```

```
<? var data = getData(); ?>
<? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
  <tr>
    <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
      <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
    <? } ?>
  </tr>
<? } ?>
```

Client Side. Call this function from onclick attribute or use the `HtmlElement.addEventlistener` method.

```
function refreshTable(){
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(html => {
    document.querySelector('table').innerHTML = html;
  })
  .withFailureHandler((error) => console.error(error.message))
  .includeFromTemplate('table')
}
```